# eliminar caracteres no alfanumericos en r

Tags: string, r, data

tengo una funcion en r que a partir de distintas cadenas de texto las analiza y me devuelve todas la palabras que contienen las distintas cadenas.

```
data <- searchTwitter(input$select, n=input$numtweets)
data_text <- sapply(data, function(x) x$getText())
data_text<- gsub('http+', '', data_text)
data_text_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(data_text))
data_text_corpus <- tm_map(data_text_corpus,
                                     content_transformer(function(x) iconv(x, to='UTF-8', sub='byte'))
)
data_text_corpus <- tm_map(data_text_corpus, removeNumbers)
data_text_corpus <- tm_map(data_text_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
data_text_corpus <- tm_map(data_text_corpus, removePunctuation)
data_text_corpus <- tm_map(data_text_corpus, function(x)removeWords(x,stopwords(kind = "SMART")))
```

el problema es que devuelve strings de caracters no alfanumericos como:

```
asthma  
â€Ã 
â€žÃ    
ÂÃ   
attack
```

solo quiero que me devuelve palabras como:

```
asthma  
attack
```

Comment: lo he solucionado cambiando:  content_transformer(function(x) iconv(x, to='UTF-8', sub='byte')) por    content_transformer(function(x) iconv(x, to='ASCII', sub='byte')). pero gracias igaulmente

Comment: Francesc, puedes publicar la respuesta tú mismo y más tarde aceptar tu propia respuesta como la válida.

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente la solución de @lois6b es la adecuada, lo que resta es "aplicarla" al data.frame o vector, algo así:

```
> v <- c('â€žÃA', 'AA')
> v[grepl('^[A-Za-z0-9]+$', v)]
[1] "AA"
```

Comment: gracias por aplicarla haha no tenia ni idea de cómo y sin un entorno de pruebas para toquetear poco iba a descubrir solo hshahah

Answer (score 1):

No conozco [r](/questions/tagged/r) pero por lo que he visto buscando por ahi,  esta funcion:

```
grepl('^[A-Za-z0-9]+$', str1)
```

usa expresiones regulares ([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)) para determinar si en el `str1` hay o no caracteres alfanumericos. Devuelve `true` si todos los caracteres lo son, y `false` en caso contrario.

Explicacion de la regex:

- `^` -> inicio de la cadena
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` -> caracteres de la A-Z (y en minusculas) y 0-9 para numeros
- `+` -> 1 o más repeticiones
- `$` -> fin de la cadena

<sub>Basado en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33073092/3045491)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Al importar, por ejemplo, tweets, puede haber información útil escondida. Un tema previo al mencionado por Patricio es "convertir" el texto:

Sea el siguiente ejemplo:

```
x <- c('asthma', 'â€Ã', 'â€žÃ', 'ÂÃ', 'attack', 'gro\u00df', 'Ekstrøm', 'Jöreskog', 'bißchen', 'Zürcher')
```

Se puede intentar no perder información de dos maneras:

```
x2 <- stringi::stri_trans_general(x, "latin-ascii")
x2
```

[1] "asthma"         "a\u0080A"       "a\u0080\u009eA" "AA"
[5] "attack"         "gross"          "Ekstrom"        "Joreskog"
[9] "bisschen"       "Zurcher"

Que para este caso funciona para gross, que estaba escrito con un caracter UNICODE y los caracteres suecos los convierte. O este otro:

```
x3 <- iconv(x,'utf-8','ascii', sub = '')
x3
```

[1] "asthma"  ""        ""        ""        "attack"  "gro"     "Ekstrm"

[8] "Jreskog" "bichen"  "Zrcher"

En donde elimina caracteres de otros idiomas o codificaciones, pero deja los latin1.

Luego se pueden eliminar las cadenas de longitud cero.

El caso es probar, para no perder información.